# Extracting date values from hashes within Ruby array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, datetime, hash

I have an array that contains a series of hashes as listed below.

```
[{:pgs=>6, :oo=>"No", :ms_no=>"D3273", :auth=>"Johnson", :ms_recd=>"Mar 14", :ready_for_ce=>"Mar 15", :proj_back_from_ce=>"Apr 1", :final_ok=>"Jul 25", :pub_date=>"Aug 5", :notes=>" "}, 
{:pgs=>17, :oo=>"No", :ms_no=>"R4382", :auth=>"Jacobs", :ms_recd=>"Apr 12", :ready_for_ce=>"Apr 16", :proj_back_from_ce=>"May 17", :final_ok=>"Jul 10", :pub_date=>"June 10 ", :notes=>" "},
{:pgs=>15, :oo=>"No",  :ms_no=>"L3291", :auth=>"Smith", :ms_recd=>"Mar 25", :ready_for_ce=>"Mar 26", :proj_back_from_ce=>"Apr 22", :final_ok=>"Jun 21", :pub_date=>"Aug 10 ", :notes=>"Au prompted for cx 4/30", nil=>" 5/15."}]
```

I need to take two take two date values within each hash: the one with the key `:ms_recd` and the one with the key `:pub_date`. I then will determine how many days spanned between the two date ranges (for example, 18 days).

Fortunately, I have the last part pretty much figured out. I just need to do

```
ms_recd1 = DateTime.parse('Apr 24')
pub_date1 = DateTime.parse('Aug 15')
(pub_date1 - ms_recd1).to_i
```

Which returns `115` (meaning 115 days). So let's say for three hashes, I'll pull out date ranges of 115, 162, and 94 days, and then I'd average it to 123.6 days.

My question is, how do I pull these date values out of this array to do this? I feel like this should be simple, but I can't figure out how it should work.

Comment: `:ms_recd_from_ed` does not exist in your example.

Comment: This is pretty straightforward. What have you tried? Show some of your code.

Comment: I hope you know the pub_date in the second hash is an empty string??

Comment: robertodecurnex and bjhaid, I've edited the question correspondingly -- thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, how do I pull these date values out of this array to do this?

You could write as to get those dates :

```
 array.map{|h| h.values_at(:ms_recd,:pub_date)}
```

Full solution as **@robertodecurnex** commented :

```
 array.map{|h| (DateTime.parse(h[:pub_date]) - DateTime.parse(h[:ms_recd])).to_i}
```

Comment: @CodeBiker you can also `collect` all the pairs and get the collection of results `array.map{|h| h.values_at(:ms_recd,:pub_date)}.collect{|a| (DateTime.parse(a.last) - DateTime.parse(a.first)).to_i}`

Comment: @CodeBiker or `array.map{|h| (DateTime.parse(h[:pub_date]) - DateTime.parse(h[:ms_recd])).to_i}`

Comment: @robertodecurnex Absolutely right!! I didn't give this as OP asked only to collect hash values.. But now updated.. Thanks